# How to display PNG image in ARCore?

Tags: android, image, arcore

I want to display 2d png image in Arcore. I don’t want to use obj, .smf ,imgdb file, and 3D image.  I have already referred many links but none of them showing how to display only 2d png image using Arcore.

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart

Comment: use the provided tool to reference your png in a new imgdb file. https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/arcoreimg

Comment: But that PNG image is not static means All image get by the server

Comment: I don't really know arcore, but it looks like nothing prevents you from directly adding images to an image database at runtime: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/guide

Comment: I know I have checked example and augmented image use obj file. I don't want it because I want to display a simple png file

Comment: Can you clarify where/how in 3D space you want to draw your png or is in a frame for the scene (like a heads up display).

Comment: I want to display a 2D png image on the wall and repeat this image

Comment: You should transform your 2d image in a 3D obj. Put his "back" as bottom. Use vertical recognition. So you can anchor the object in the wall

Comment: @Canato can  you give me a simple example?

Comment: Another option is use a card with a layout in insert a ImageView in this layout, but will not look like a print in the wall, will look more like a tag in somepoint that you can see from any direction

Comment: @Canato Thanks for suggestion I can't apply this solution

Comment: @MaheshVayak the documentation I linked clearly shows that you can create an image database without any file, and then add jpg or png file to that database.

Comment: @njzk2 I was referred but It returns 3D object render and I want the 2D image. If you have Idea about then please post answer or sample code link.

Answer (score 8):

If you use [ViewRenderable of Sceneform](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/create-renderables), then you can create a wall in AR space from 2D png image just like standard android widgets.

This is an example of layout xml for ViewRenderable. As you know, it's just a layout xml for Android apps ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageCard"
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="197dp"
    android:src="@drawable/Your_Image_Resource" />
```

And you can get ImageView instance in your Java code like below to set a source image dynamically.

```
ViewRenderable.builder()
    .setView(fragment.getContext(), R.layout.imgboard)
    .build()
    .thenAccept(renderable -> {
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)renderrable.getView();
    });
```

This is my sample shot with using ViewRenderable, the object on the far right was created from a png image.
[image: screenshot of sceneform AR]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Can I repeat the image because I want to scan wall and scan area repeat the same image.

Comment: I would also be interessted in such an approach

Comment: Can you give and example without using Sceneform, only using Google ARCore, because Sceneform is deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62694454/8362967

Comment: It crashes in my app

Answer (score 0):

I made a free app that tiles hundreds of png files (for a computer science prof). You can try it in a big area about 2x4 meters: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=a.FlatKmapAR

To start with, just take the HelloAR example and replace the Andy.obj file with a square.obj that's only a square object (less than 10 lines of text) and replace Andy.png with your square.png file. Since they use the wave object format, that's the easiest way I know how to do it. Once you've got that, to tile them create a grid.obj with multiple squares, and so forth...

Comment: Hi YinOrYan: Can you provide further information or a github project? There are several vague points here. "replace the Andy.obj file with a square.obj that's only a square object (less than 10 lines of text)", I don't understand this. Then I replace the png with my own png? Thx

Comment: basti, The HelloAR example comes with Google's AR Core open source code. It uses only one .obj file and one .png file. The .obj is a very complex model of the Android Bug Character. All you have got to do is replace it with a simple square or grid. The .obj format in very straightforward and has been around since the 1980's. You don't need any app to generate it. Just key in a few lines of text...

Comment: I cloned the sample from here (https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/9461160f6b1ebaf9070368b52795444267b7acab) then I try to create a .obj with square. If I open it with Paint3D it looks like what I want, but I downloaded a image from the internet to replace the png and all I see is a plane with orange color.     (    v 0.000000 2.000000 0.000000
    v 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    v 2.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    v 2.000000 2.000000 0.000000
    f 1 2 3 4) 

I created a github project: https://github.com/basti12354/AndroidARExample (Maybe you can take a look)

Comment: First of all there's some extra leading spaces that may be a problem, but then you need a vt and some slashes in the f's. Also, your image should have x=y like 1024x1024 or the Mona Lisa is going to be a fat-chick, or worse, not show up at all...

Comment: See the new answer above, since these comment cannot display code...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it actually needs some vt to define the texture, in addition to at least one vn to define a normal, so then the f needs / for polygon/texture/normal like this:

```
v 0.000000 2.000000 0.000000
v 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 2.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 2.000000 2.000000 0.000000
vt 0.0 0.0
vt 1.0 0.0
vt 1.0 1.0
vt 1.0 1.0
vn 0.0 1.0 0.0
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 4/4/1
```

Comment: thx, I try to use this and as you suggested I used 1024x1024 px image. I updated my github repository. But if I try to place it, it is warped and has the wrong color. https://github.com/basti12354/AndroidARExample/blob/master/Screenshot_20201207_120931_com.google.ar.core.examples.java.helloar.jpg (I used a round captain america icon with 1024x1024, but also Mona Lisa was not correctly displayed)

Comment: Oh sorry, that's probably because I just tacked-on the last 6 lines to your file, so you will have to change the order the vt's to match the top...