# Display PNG or Image with ARCore and Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm trying to display a image after ARCore displays the overlay on the detected marker but I'm not sure how to start.

I saw this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251070/how-to-display-png-image-in-arcore) but the answer and person was using Android Studio. How would you do it in Unity?

Comment: What have you tried in Unity that isn't working?

Comment: Have you tried using unity image and rendering it when augmented image tracking state is tracking?