# Displaying .png or .jpeg images in ARcore mobile application?

Tags: java, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform, android-augmented-reality

I have to display a 2d image and don't want to use 3d objects with .obj file.Is it even possible? And how to do it?

Comment: check this post it would be helpful 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251070/how-to-display-png-image-in-arcore

Answer (score 0):

> You can use three robust approaches, in your case, to create Sceneform's `Renderable`:

- **First approach** is to create a **`plane primitive`** with a `.jpg` or `.png` texture assigned to it.

  ```
  ModelRenderable plane = ShapeFactory.makeCube(
                                       new Vector3(5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f), // size
                                       new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // center
                                       material);
  ```
- **Second approach** is to create a `ViewRenderable` from standard `Android Widgets`.

  ```
  ViewRenderable.builder()
      .setView(this, R.layout.test_view)
      .build()
      .thenAccept(renderable -> testViewRenderable = renderable);
  ```
- **Third approach** is to import a plane made in 3d authoring tool (Maya, 3dsMax, Cinema4D, etc).

  ```
  ModelRenderable.builder()
      .setSource(this, RenderableSource.builder().setSource(
          this,
          Uri.parse(ASSET),
          RenderableSource.SourceType.OBJ)
          .setScale(2.0f)
          .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.ROOT)
          .build())
      .setRegistryId(ASSET)
      .build()
  ```